# Перекрытия виджетов

Tags: c++, qt

Как узнать, что некоторый виджет есть в области другого виджета без вычислений размеров виджетов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (widget1->geometry().intersects(widget2->geometry()))
    //пересекается
else
    //не пересекается
```